# Traceback errors on python script within the discord\client.py error?

Tags: python, bots, discord

I am unable to run any python code within Visual Studio Code for discord correctly. The error message is persistent, and regardless of what method I use to access the file, the error keeps returning. the code is as follows:

```py
def read_token():
    path = '/path/used/to.txt'
    with open(path, "r") as f:
        lines = f.read()
        return lines[0].strip()

token = read_token()
print(token)

try:
    bot.run(token)
except discord.errors.LoginFailure as e:
    print('login failed, ERROR 401 unauthorized')
```

doing this will output this on the terminal:

```
<function read_token at 0x7f2d0edba268>
login failed, ERROR 401 unauthorized
```

The error gives this information :

```
  File "/home/falwaeth/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 256, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/home/falwaeth/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 220, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 UNAUTHORIZED (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/falwaeth/BotDev/bot.py", line 32, in <module>
    bot.run(f'{token}')
  File "/home/falwaeth/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 640, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/home/falwaeth/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/falwaeth/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 584, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/home/falwaeth/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 442, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/home/falwaeth/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 260, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
```

What I do not understand is the improper token. If I change the bot.run() to have the actual token in it, it will work. The permission of the .txt file is set to be able to be read by everyone. Any ideas?

The bot.run() will only work if the token is inside, i don't think i was meant to read from a .txt file in python. I've changed some things on this working directory, it now runs python3.7.5. I found another issue upon entering this code:

```
    path = '/path/used/to.txt'
    with open(path,'r') as f:  
          lines = f.readlines()
          return lines[0].strip()

token = read_token
bot.run(token)
```

gives me this as an error now:

```
  File "/home/falwaeth/BotDev/welcomeBot.py", line 31, in <module>
    bot.run(token)
  File "/home/falwaeth/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 640, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/home/falwaeth/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/falwaeth/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 584, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/home/falwaeth/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 442, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'strip'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/falwaeth/BotDev/welcomeBot.py", line 31, in <module>
    bot.run(token)
  File "/home/falwaeth/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 640, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/home/falwaeth/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/falwaeth/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 584, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/home/falwaeth/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 442, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

any idea why?

Comment: Could you share your code?  It looks like you're not passing a string to `client.run`

Comment: `read_token` looks like it might be a function.  Did you intend to call it?  `token = read_token()`

Comment: i fixed that with the same error presented; see above changes at line 6, 7 and 10

Answer (score 0):

`f.read()` will return the contents of the file as a string, so `lines[0].strip()` will be the first character of that file.  I suspect you want this instead:

```
path = '/path/used/to.txt'
with open(path, "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    return lines[0].strip()
```

Comment: ive tried several iterations of this; but ive found a new problem. will edit original question to reflect.